# ASP.NET not recognizing dataset and data adapter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net, dataset

My ASP.NET web application is not recognizing DataSet and DataAdapter. Which namespace is required to create a new DataSet?

Comment: Are you saying you don't know what namespaces to include with the "using" directive?

Answer (score 6):

Namespace

```
using System.Data;
```

OR Directly

```
System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.Data`

For a typed DataSet, you can check the typed DataSet file's (.XSD file) .CS/.VB file; it will show the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are going to need to reference `System.Data.dll` and here are the two types you are looking for with their fully-qualified names:

> [`System.Data.DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx)
>   [`System.Data.Common.DataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx)

So add these `using` statements at the top of your file:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
```

Answer (score 1):

**DataSet** class belongs to `System.Data` namespace.

For provider classes use one of the following namespace,

**System.Data.OleDB******, System.Data.SqlClient, **System.Data.Odbc**, **System.Data.OracleClient** or vendor specific namespace.

Answer (score 1):

just import system.data
and imports system.data.oledb

in c# replace imports by using.